# Proof about diagonalizable Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

The proof said the following, let $A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $A^r=I_{n \times n}$ for some $r \in \mathbb{N},r>0$ then $A$ is diagonalizable.
Mi attempt is the next, since $A$ is equal to the identity matrix, then we can approach the jordan normal form of the $A$, but, i can´t see, the zise of the jordan blocks. someone who give me a hint, or in her case the proof

Comment: Why do you say that $A$ is equal to the identity matrix?

Comment: $A$ not is necessary the identity matrix, the hipotesis is $A^r$ is the idenity matrix for some $r \in \mathbb{N}$$

Comment: But **you** wrote that $A$ is equal to the identity matrix!